# Should it be "has" or "have"?

Tags: grammaticality

I found this in an exam paper:

> A German mother and teacher has written to the newspaper about libraries.

Shouldn't it be "A German mother and teacher have written to the newspaper about libraries." since there are multiple people? "Has" does not sound right to me.

Comment: Are there multiple people, or is there one person who is both a mother and a teacher?

Comment: I only see one person there, a person who is not only a mother but also a teacher. It’s like saying that *Our Master and Commander is off-duty at this hour, but can be woken at need.*

Comment: Here the mother and the teacher are one person, otherwise it would have been 'a mother and a teacher'. So a singular verb 'has' is correct.

Comment: One "hint"  that the noun phrase is talking about one person is the single use of the indefinite article. If the noun phrase  were *A German mother and **a** teacher* then it would be ambiguous, with the number of people (one or two) derived from context.

Answer (score 5):

If it's referring to one person who is both a mother and teacher (which, at a glance, is what is inferred) then "has" is correct. If it's two separate people who have written in then "have" would be correct instead.

explained here: http://writingexplained.org/has-vs-have-difference

The verb "have" is conjugated as "has" when it's one person ("he/she **has** joined the gym"), whereas when there are multiple people it's "have" ("They **have** joined the gym").

Comment: Done, I hope that's clearer.

Comment: It wasn't *unclear*, we just prefer answers have support because most people who stumble upon answers want more than what looks like just an opinion. Your edit is a perfect addition.